# How to get the provider of firebase authentication without signing in in android application

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app I have some users which have signed in with google as a provider. Now if these users tried to sign up with email and password I need to show them a message that they can't sign with this provider . The exception that I gets is "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE" which is the same exception that comes if the user signs in before with email and password provider . So I need to know the provider of the userEmail because the exception isn't enough for me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the provider of firebase authentication without signing in in android application

There is no need for that. As in the official documentation, the simplest solution would be to [link multiple auth providers to an account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

Answer (score 1):

While Alex' answer is probably the right solution for your use-case, I just want to point out that you *can* find out the providers that are associated with a given email address by calling [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)).